# changes applied to v-model does not trigger writable computed methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vuejs3` with `options api`

as shown in the code posted below, the vue components `RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo` has a radio button as an input. the `RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo` is a child component. i make the binding in the parent component as shown below in section `paretn component` via `v-model`.
the  `parent component` has a `button` that once clicked the method `onDigitizePolygon` will be invoked, and causes the value of `vModelTimeSeriesAgo` in the parent component to change, hence, i expected the `v-model` to reflect the changes in ‘RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo.vu’ accordingly.

but what happens is, despite `vModelTimeSeriesAgo` in the parent components changes, that never trigger any changes in the child component `RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo`. the writable computed methods never executed.

please let me know why that is happenening and in case i created the `v-model` wrongly, please show me how to make it correctly.

**RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo.vue**:

```
<template>
    <cds-radio>
        <input
            type="radio"
            :value="vModelTimeSeriesAgo"
            @input="$emit('update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo', $event.target.value)"
            @change="onTimeSeriesAgoChanged()"/>
    </cds-radio>
</template>

<script>
import { NDVIGuiConstants } from './resources/NDVIComparisonGuiConstants.js';
export default {
    name: 'RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo',
    date() {
        return {};
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        tempTextTimeSeriesAgo: {
            type: String,
            default: NDVIGuiConstants.CONST_RADIO_BUTTON_TIME_SERIES_AGO.description,
        },
    },
    emits: ['update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo'],
    computed: {
        vModelTimeSeriesAgo: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.vModelTimeSeriesAgo:', this.vModelTimeSeriesAgo);
                return this.vModelTimeSeriesAgo;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.vModelTimeSeriesAgo:', value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onTimeSeriesAgoChanged() {
            console.log('onTimeSeriesAgoChanged');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**parent component**

```
<template>
    <button @click="onDigitizePolygon()"></button>
    <RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo v-model:vModelTimeSeriesAgo="vModelTimeSeriesAgo"></RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo>
</template>

<script>
    let vModelTimeSeriesAgo = ref('');
    export default  {
    data() {
        return {
            vModelTimeSeriesAgo,
        }
    },
    components: {
        RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo,
    },
    methods: {
        onDigitizePolygon() {
            vModelTimeSeriesAgo.value += '#';
    },
    immediate: true,
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

TL,DR; Two issues need addressing to make your code work:

- you haven't declared `vModelTimeSeriesAgo` as a `prop`
- it's not clear why you're using `type="radio"`.

---

### A. Declare the `prop`

In order for `v-model:something="whatever"` to work, you ***need to declare `something` as a `prop` and the emit in the child component.*** ***<sup>1</sup>***

**parent**

```html
<some-child v-model:something="whatever" />
```

**some-child**

```js
export default {
  props: ['something'], 
  emits: ['update:something']
}
```

```html
<input :value="something" @input="$emit('update:something', $event.target.value)" />
```

Alternatively, you can define a local computed in child:

```
import { emit } from 'vue'
export default {
  props: ['something'],
  emits: ['update:something'],
  computed: {
    localSomething: {
      get() { return this.something },
      set(val) { emit('update:something', val)
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
export default {
  props: ['something'],
  emits: ['update:something'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const localSomething = computed({
      get() { return props.something },
      set(val) { emit('update:something', val) }
    })
    return { localSomething }
  }
}
```

or

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['something'])
const emit = defineEmits(['update:something'])
const localSomething = computed({
  get() { return props.something },
  set(val) { emit('update:something', val) }
})
</script>
```

and use with `v-model`:

```html
<input v-model="localSomething" />
```

Now changing the input value in child component will update the parent `whatever`.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - The implicit `v-model` variable name is `modelValue` (when used as `<some-child v-model="whatever" />`. But you ***still need to declare the prop and the emit***:

```js
//...
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue']
```

---

### B. Why are you using `type="radio"`?

All of the above apply to `<input type="text" />`. At this point, it's not clear to me why you're using `type="radio"` with only one option.

Radio buttons are typically used with multiple input elements all sharing the same `v-model`, each having a different `value`. When one of them is clicked, the `v-model` gets the `value` from that input and the previously selected radio inputs from the same group get unselected.

In the above example, using Options API, a child component would look something like this:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    values: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
  }),
  props: ['something'],
  emits: ['update:something'],
  computed: {
    localSomething: {
      get() {
        return this.something
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit('update:something', val)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <label v-for="item in values" :key="item">
    <input v-model="localSomething" type="radio" :value="item" />{{ item }}
  </label>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sky-z762nw?file=/src/App.vue). And same, in [`<script setup>`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-glitter-dyd5ss?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: But ‘ vModelTimeSeriesAgo’ in ‘ RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo.vue’ is declared in ‘computed’, thus it can not be declared in ‘props’,..right?

Comment: @Ammsmb, I would argue it's the other way around. It ***must*** be declared in `props` if you want the parent `v-model` to work. Thus it ***can't*** be declared in `computed`, ...right? Why not call the computed something else? Like `vmtsa`? Or `somethingElse`?

Comment: Ok fine, let’s assume I I declared vModelTimeSeriesAgo as props. And called  the writable computed as Vmtsa. Where should vmtsa be used and how please?

Comment: You may call the prop whatever you want. In order to work it has to be the exact same name used after `v-model:` in parent template. Sorry if my answer didn't make that sufficiently clear. I have already shown in the answer how to consume it. You can create a local computed and use `v-model` or use the `prop` and the `emit` directly on `<input />` in `:value` and `@input`. I'm not sure how I can make my answer clearer.

Comment: To answer your latest question: use `vmtsa` computed on the `<input />`'s `v-model`: `<input v-model="vmtsa" />`. That should do it. If you have any trouble, consider importing your project into codesandbox or similar, so I can debug it and see what's broken. I'm afraid without a *runnable* [mcve] I can't help further.

Comment: Thanks, I will acknowledge once tested

Comment: I just had a look at your parent component. You're combining `<script setup>` syntax with Options API with an Options API watch syntax. That's never going to work. You don't need the `ref()` wrapper, all members of `data` are already reactive and they don't need `.value`. So only keep `data: () => ({ vModelTimeSeriesAgo: '' })` and make the method: `onDigitizePolygon() { this.vModelTimeSeriesAgo += '#' }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255026/discussion-between-tao-and-amrmsmb).